# what is the meaning of componentsSeparatedByString in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

what is the meaning of `componentsSeparatedByString` in objective c?

```
NSArray *customerNameArray=[[[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"CustomerNames"] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

how is it used in the above line of code,here `arrTemp` is an object of a MSMutableArray.

Comment: Please, always read documentation if you have questions like “What does this method do?”. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Answer (score 9):

`componentsSeparatedByString:` is like `StringTokenizer` in Java. It splits the given string into an array based on the given separator. For example,

```
NSString *namesStr =  @"John;Michael;Jason";
NSArray *namesArray = [namesStr componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
```

As the result, `namesArray` will contain the strings `@"John"`, `@"Michael"` and `@"Jason"`.

Comment: What will happen if the string is like this: @"John;;;Michael;;Jason" ?

Answer (score 5):

[`NSString - componentsSeparatedByString`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_35)

> Returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by a given separator.

It's like `String.split()` in many other languages ([Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [PHP](http://php.net/explode), [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)...)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following string.

```
// [[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"CustomerNames"] => "John,Steve,Bob"
```

When you do this:

```
NSArray *names = [[[arrTemp objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"CustomerNames"] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
// names => ["John", "Steve", "Bob"]
```

So you can use those things:

```
[names objectAtIndex:0] // => John
[names count] // => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentsSeparatedByString` - returns an array containing substrings from the receiver that have been divided by a given separator.

The substrings in the array appear in the order they did in the receiver. Adjacent occurrences of the separator string produce empty strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with the separator, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty. For example, this code fragment:

```
NSString *list = @"Karin, Carrie, David";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@", "];
```

produces the array @[@"Karin", @"Carrie", @"David"].

If list begins with a comma and space—for example, @", Norman, Stanley, Fletcher"—the array has these contents: @[@"", @"Norman", @"Stanley", @"Fletcher"].

If list has no separators—for example, @"Karin"—the array contains the string itself, in this case @[@"Karin"].

Apple Reference Document: [componentsSeparatedByString:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-componentsseparatedbystring?language=objc)