# Remove underscore From a String

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string as in "aa_bb_cc". I want to convert it into a single string of "aa bb cc" with spaces between each of aa, bb and cc. How can I do that ?? Thanks.

Comment: Is it really so hard to use a search of the documentation or of Stack Overflow?

Comment: I searched .. but could not find an answer to my query. I am sorry.

Comment: Calling shenanigans on that one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
 str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_"
                                     withString:@" "];
```

Comment: Search for componentsSeparatedByString method of NSString and try to get your required string.Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009379/what-is-the-meaning-of-componentsseparatedbystring-in-objective-c

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
```

[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

Answer (score 3):

Use  **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString** of NSString

```
 NSString *str = @"aa_bb_cc";
 [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[str replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" " options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
var str = "aa_bb_cc"

str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.2:

```
let input = "upload_FfAPfl-icon.png"

let output = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: "") // "uploadFfAPfl-icon.png"
```