# How to Trim a String in Swift based on a character

Tags: swift, string

I would like to trim this string, so that I can extract the filename, which is always preceded by an "_" (underscore).  What is the best way to do this?

https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/RXI2cT/upload_FfAPfl-icon.png

I would like the result to be FfAPfl-icon.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove underscore From a String in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186983/remove-underscore-from-a-string-in-xcode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use String method rangeOfString:

```
let link = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/RXI2cT/upload_FfAPfl-icon.png"
if let range = link.rangeOfString("_") {
    let fileName = link.substringFromIndex(range.endIndex)
    print(fileName)  // "FfAPfl-icon.png\n"
}
```

---

**Xcode 8 beta 3 • Swift 3**

```
if let range = link.range(of: "_") {
    let fileName = link.substring(from: range.upperBound)
    print(fileName) // "FfAPfl-icon.png\n"
}
```

Comment: Hi Leo Dabus. Can you please check my question if when you available. :-). I did't get any help yet. I think little bit mistake are in my code. I think you can resolve it. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561293/avplayer-stop-uiactivityindicator-before-playing

Answer (score 3):

Since it is an URL, you can get to the string via:

**Swift version 3**

```
let url = URL(string: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/brewerydbapi/beer/RXI2cT/upload_FfAPfl-icon.png")
let component = url?.lastPathComponent?.characters.split(separator:"_").map(String.init)

print(component?.last)// Optional("FfAPfl-icon.png")
```

**In Swift version 2.2 or 3**

```
let url = NSURL(string: 
let component = url?.lastPathComponent?.characters.split{$0 == "_"}.map(String.init)

print(component?.last)
```

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 3.X and swift 4.0**

```
let strUrl = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HUNcbm9sLaY"

if let range = strUrl.range(of: "=") {

     let strIdentifier = strUrl.substring(from: range.upperBound)
     print("Identifier:\(strIdentifier)")


 }
```