# How to take NSRange in swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am very much new to swift language. I am performing some business logic which needs to take `NSRange` from given String.

Here is my requirement,
Given Amount =  "144.44"
Need `NSRange` of only cent part i.e. after "."

Is there any API available for doing this?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nsrange/

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. There is the function `NSMakeRange` that takes 2 integers as input and returns a range. Or are you asking how to search for a string and return an `NSRange` that represents a substring (like "everything after the decimal"?)

Comment: Or, do you really need an `NSRange` or a `Range<Int>` from the substring? It depends what you are going to do with it.

Comment: @Duncan C, Yes I need NSRange object which will represent "everything after decimal".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38570678/2303865

Comment: You can use `NSMakeRange(loc: Int, len: Int)` to create a NSRange, after having find the location of the "." and the lenght of cent part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a regex-based search to find the range:

```
let str : NSString = "123.45"
let rng : NSRange = str.range("(?<=[.])\\d*$", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)
```

Regular expression `"(?<=[.])\\d*$"` means "zero or more digits following a dot character `'.'` via look-behind, all the way to the end of the string `$`."

Comment: OP uses `String` type, so he needs type cast, but solution is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `substring` from a given `string` you can use `componentsSeparatedByString`

Example :

```
var number: String = "144.44";
var numberresult= number.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
```

then you can get components as :

```
var num1: String = numberresult [0]
var num2: String = numberresult [1]
```

hope it help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use `rangeOfString` and `substringFromIndex`:

```
let string = "123.45"
if let index = string.rangeOfString(".") {
    let cents = string.substringFromIndex(index.endIndex)
    print("\(cents)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another version that uses Swift Ranges, rather than NSRange

Define the function that returns an optional Range:

```
func centsRangeFromString(str: String) -> Range<String.Index>? {
    let characters = str.characters
    guard let dotIndex = characters.indexOf(".") else { return nil }

    return Range(dotIndex.successor() ..< characters.endIndex)
}
```

Which you can test with:

```
let r = centsRangeFromString(str)
// I don't recommend force unwrapping here, but this is just an example.
let cents = str.substringWithRange(r!)
```

[image: Playground example]